# Python Pexpect: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'dict'

Tags: python, string, pexpect

When I try to run the following pexpect command i get the error: T`ypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'dict'`. I do not really understand why I am getting this error. When I do a print of the string I am outputting the results are what I expect.

**My code:**

```
p.sendline("sudo date -s \"%(easterndate)s\"") % locals()
```

**Print test of the same string:**

```
print "string ouput: " + "sudo date -s \"%(easterndate)s\"" % locals()
    output: sudo date -s "Tue Mar 26 14:25:51 EDT 2013"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
p.sendline("sudo date -s \"%(easterndate)s\"" % locals())
```

Otherwise the `%` is applied to the result of the `sendline` call.

Comment: does there need to be a "\r" when do a `p.sendline` or is this implied?

Comment: @WorkerBee I have no idea why you want to add a carriage return at the end of the line, anyway the [documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-sendline) states that a *line feed* is automatically added at the end.